# Find size of dictionary object in VBA

Tags: vba, dictionary, size

What is the simplest way in VBA to determine the size (i.e., number of keys) in a dictionary object?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As in a `Scripting.Dictionary`? just use its [`.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9h9579(v=vs.84).aspx) property.

Answer (score 4):

For the number of keys (not items) you should use `.Keys` property, via `UBound(Dictionary.Keys)` since its an array

Comment: It's an array with `0` as lower bound. So the actual count is 1 + the result of this function.